# Python Gdal: Count pixels having a specific range of values

Tags: python, raster, gdal, pixel, count

I have few hundred raster files and I want to count the number of pixels having values within a specific range. Following code works well when using `==` operator e.g., `raster_file == 25`, but gives totally wrong results when I use a range e.g.,  `(raster_file >= 0) & (raster_file <= 25)`

```
import os, sys
import numpy as np
import gdalnumeric
path = ('dir')
os.chdir(path)
for rasters in os.listdir(path):
    raster_file = gdalnumeric.LoadFile(rasters)
    pixel_count = ((raster_file =>0) & (raster_file <= 25)).sum()
    print(pixel_count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, it should be:

```
((raster_file <=0) + (raster_file >= 25)).sum()
```

Comment: Syntax runs perfectly. And I was able to figure out where the problem was. I checked for the `no-data` value of the raster files and that was unfortunately set to `0` and these zeros were counted as data.